# Is there a way to get a feed of new questions and answers being posted to an SO site ?

Tags: support

The title says it all.

I would like to read questions and answers (for that matter, also responses) in the order they were posted and may be get notified when new ones arrive. This way for some (say favorite questions) I can keep tab of new comments and answers instead of remembering to visit the page every now and then.

Currently I know I can get notified by email when new answers are posted to my questions and when I visit a new page or refresh I get notified of new responses needing my attention.

Is there any way to get notified of (filtered) updates via an rss feed ? (Say, a questions feed or answers feed to selected question etc ?)

To state the case completely, I login to Ubuntu SE from multiple computers at work and at home with varying frequency and therefore the "new responses since last visit" presented before my user name is not really effective... not as much as an rss feed would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are RSS links at the bottom right of each question (and tags too) as well as the home page.

Comment: Indeed ! I think I am too used to huge orange rss icons starting at me prominently from, like, the center of webpages & blogs that I completely ignored the discreet one here. Thanks Jorge !

Answer (score 2):

Often you can use [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to prune down or meld RSS feeds into something more tailored to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools available for the StackExchange network that aren't actually provided by StackOverflow, Inc but rather by users interacting with the StackExchange API. One such example is [Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-with-a-feed-browser-and-email-s) created by our very own [George Edison](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/george-edison) which provides additional features to the already existent RSS feeds provided by the site.

Most pages on AskUbuntu already have RSS feeds in basic ATOM form as pointed out by Jorge Castro